# mapserver 5.4.2 fcgi error

Tags: fastcgi, mapserver

I'm trying to compile mapserver 5.4.2 on a solaris machine and I'm running into problems.
I'm using the following configure parameters:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/apps/mapserver-5.4.2 \
                    --with-ogr=$HOME/local/bin/gdal-config \
                    --with-gdal=$HOME/local/bin/gdal-config \
                    --with-httpd=$HOME/local/bin/httpd \
                    --with-curl-config=$HOME/local/bin/curl-config \
                    --with-proj=$HOME/local \
                    --with-gd=$HOME/local \
                    --with-freetype=$HOME/local \
                    --with-agg=$HOME/src/agg-2.5 \
                    --with-jpeg \
                    --with-tiff \
                    --with-png \
                    --with-wms \
                    --with-wmsclient \
                    --with-wfs \
                    --with-wfsclient \
                    --with-zlib \
                    --without-ld-shared \
                    --with-postgis=$HOME/local/pgsql8110/bin/pg_config \
                    --with-fastcgi=$HOME/local
```

The error I get is:

```
checking FastCGI support... requested.
checking for FCGI_Accept in -lfcgi... no
configure: error: Unable to link against -L/home/ogclive/local/lib -lfcgi
```

Any ideas what that error means and how I can solve it?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Your with parameter "--with-fastcgi=$HOME/local" is incorrect. On my machines it is "--with-fastcgi=/usr/lib".

This is location of the required files libfcgi.so and libfcgi.a.

Sorry this took so long.